# python key word extraction from the list

Tags: python

suppose there's a list called `listfile`:

```
listfile = ['apple_1','apple_2','apple_3','banana_1','cherry_1','cherry_2']
```

How can I extract data which has the keyword name '`apple_`'?

Is there any simple way so that I can use on long array of list file?

I want just like this following example:

```
listfile_1 = ['apple_1','apple_2','apple_3']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions are efficient for this:

```
listfile_1 = [x for x in listfile if 'apple_' in x]
```

Or, if the string you are searching for must appear at the start:

```
listfile_1 = [x for x in listfile if x.startswith('apple_')]
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this could be:

```
listfile = ['apple_1','apple_2','apple_3','banana_1','cherry_1','cherry_2']
result = []
for l in listfile:
    if "apple_" in l:
        result.append(l)
print result
```

> **OUTPUT**:
>
> ["apple_1", "apple_2", "apple_3"]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
listfile = ['apple_1','apple_2','apple_3','banana_1','cherry_1','cherry_2']
listfile_1 = []
for elt in listfile:
   if elt[:6]=='apple_':
      listfile_1 += [ elt ]
```

OR

```
listfile_1 = [elt for elt in listfile if elt[:6]=='apple_']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [filter built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) too.

```
listfile_1 = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('apple_'), listfile))
```